# What comes out of binary black holes at end of inspiral?

Tags: black-holes, gravitational-waves, ligo, explosions

When 2 blackholes are orbiting each other so close that they lose more energy in form of gravitational wave, this process is inspiral and is unstoppable until it explodes. This is an extremely violent event dwarfing even supernova so what is spilled out from this inspiral? What mechanisms drive this incredible explosion? Or is this just mere short burst of energy from gravitational waves which happens to create the notorious chirp in LIGO detector?

Comment: It does not explode, it merges losing more and more energy mostly in gravitational waves , (also maybe some electromagnetic  gamma rays https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.02305 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the inspiraling black holes merge into one black hole- there is no "explosion" in this process. There is a wonderful series of computer simulation videos of black hole merger put together by a team led by Kip Thorne which can be viewed on the web. If I recall where to find them, I will edit this answer to include the address.

Comment: The CalTech GW simulation group is part of the [SXS collaboration](https://www.black-holes.org/), which have their own [YouTube page](https://www.youtube.com/user/SXSCollaboration/videos) with many cool videos.

Comment: yes yes, that's the one!